# Невозможность скрыть Label

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 3 лэйблы, 2 из который надо скрыть. Делаю это не через XAML, почему не спрашивайте.
Код:

```
label2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
label3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

По идее они должны скрыться и все, однако выпадает *System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."*

Если я пытаюсь делать это через прозрачность

```
label2.Opacity = 0;
label3.Opacity = 0;
```

То выдает такую-же ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Очевидно, `label2` или `label3` равен `null`. _Ваш К. О._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы задаёте видимость Label в конструкторе, то задавайте её после функции

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: Чорт, у меня был код там, и я его случайно закомментировал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка еще может возникать, если компонент (на котором выскакивает ошибка) объявлен после компонента, в котором происходит логика (в Вашем случае скрывает видимость элемента).
Решение: перенесите объявление компонента в начало формы.